# Safari HTML 5 video tag not working inside a link tag

Tags: html, video, safari

Issue is with Safari. The video Tag.
I have placed a video tag inside a link tag.
I am trying to make a video a link.
It works on all browsers except Safari.
the page in question is here: neumatic.com
In Safari it only goes to the poster image but will not play the video.
I've tried moving the link tag further up the div tree, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't appear that a `<video>` element is even allowed within an `<a>` element. According to the [HTML specifications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is **no interactive content within** (e.g. buttons or other links).

Even though the HTML5 validator says that a video inside an anchor is valid (for the time being), I would consider a video to be interactive content, but I can't find anything that specifically lists which element in HTML5 *are* considered "interactive content."

**If it is valid:** This appears to just be a browser compatibility issue. Previously, block-level content (which would include the video element) was *not* allowed within anchors. Safari may just have bugs or implementation issues concerning block-level content at the moment, which may even be specific to the video element. You have to remember that HTML5 is still new and in development, you're bound to run across some weird glitches and issues somewhere. Try filing a bug report with Safari.

Either way, I would consider placing a video inside an anchor as bad practice, in personal opinion. Good luck.

Comment: From your link: _Interactive content: (...) video (if the controls attribute is present)_

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated. Well it's a work around. I'm actually trying to get a clickable button on top of the video. Tying to get div's to overlap is one way I guess. Thanks though, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I got a simple video to work for me on Safari 5.1.1 on OS X and discovered that it's the `poster` attribute on `<video>` that's preventing it from working in Safari, not the `<a>` wrapped around it. If you remove the `poster` attribute, it works fine on Safari. I kept your code the exactly same except for removing the `poster` attribute (except for a smaller `width` and fully qualifying the `src` so it would play, neither of which affected the outcome).

#### Another Video

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/8vTN7/

```html
<a href="http://thinkingstiff.com" target="_top">
<video controls="controls" width="592" height="252">
<source src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4">
</video>
</a>
```

#### Your Video

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/cRx4a/

Changed:

```
<video class="video-js" autoplay="" loop="" preload="" poster="_neumatic-video/neumatic-video-production-intro/neumatic-video-production_poster.jpg" id="intro">
```

To:

```
<video class="video-js" autoplay="" loop="" preload="" id="intro" >
```

Comment: Yes, i found that out too after lengthly tryouts. Thanks! It only does that on this page though, so it's a the combination link tag and poster attribute. Thanks for the help, it was a great help.